# What biproducts do vinegar eels produce?

Tags: biochemistry, microbiology

What chemicals, acids, gases or other biproducts do [vinegar eels](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Turbatrix_aceti) (Turbatrix aceti) produce (in raw vinegar and/or in the vinegar-creation process, which process may have them in environments including such as fruit scraps and fermented fruit scraps, sugar, alcohol, or water)? I know they're said to feed on acetic acid bacteria and apples.

I'm particularly curious if they produce acetic acid, carbon dioxide, enzymes, and/or vitamins, but I'm generally curious about everything they produce. I'm not sure exactly how many chemicals a single nematode species can produce (so, if it's a lot, you can narrow your answer down to what might be particularly useful to a nutritionist and/or someone making vinegar).

I thought this might be a better place to ask than Seasoned Advice, seeing as it's about biological processes, and as far as I know, little is publicly known in the culinary world about what they produce (I couldn't find any information on it).

Comment: If it's appropriate here, feel free to create a tag for nematology and add this to it.

Comment: Per wikipedia vinegar eels don't contribute to the creation of vinegar, rather they feed on the bacteria that are creating the vinegar.